# No module named 'keras_preprocessing'

Tags: jupyter

I installed python 3.9.0
and Tensorflow and Keras 2.11.0
I can see they all installed
but i can't run this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,  img_to_array
from keras_preprocessing.image import load_img
```

the input is:No module named 'keras_preprocessing'

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Keras-Preprocessing](https://pypi.org/project/Keras-Preprocessing/)

```
pip install Keras-Preprocessing
```